# ignore column if column value is null or empty for searching in mysql table

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT logic_id
FROM business_logic_details
WHERE if(form_completion != 0.00,form_completion,0) = '90'
  AND if(query_type IS NOT NULL
         OR query_type !='',query_type,0) LIKE '%domestic%'
  AND if(client_type IS NOT NULL
         OR client_type !='',client_type,0) LIKE '%existing%'
  AND if(tour_package IS NOT NULL
         OR tour_package !='',tour_package,0) LIKE '%S%'
  AND if(tour_type IS NOT NULL
         OR tour_type !='',tour_type,0) LIKE '%2%'
  AND if(currency IS NOT NULL
         OR currency !='',currency,0) = 'INR'
  AND if(country IS NOT NULL
         OR country !='',country,0) = '105'
  AND if(adults IS NOT NULL
         OR adults !='',adults,0) = '1'
  AND if(duration_of_stay IS NOT NULL
         OR duration_of_stay !='',duration_of_stay,0) = '5'
ORDER BY logic_id ASC
```

Comment: Just a comment... do you really need to use wildcards in your `query_type` and `client_type` columns?

Comment: yes,these columns have comma seperated values.we will search a value or values in these comma seperated values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COALESCE function for that:

```
SELECT logic_id
FROM business_logic_details
WHERE COALESCE(form_completion, 90) = 90
  AND COALESCE(query_type, 'domestic') LIKE '%domestic%'
        ...
```

I also strongly suggest to compare integers as integers, and not as strings:

Good: 0 = 90
Bad:  0 = '90'

Comment: this is not return expected result.same result returned as my query do.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect what you need. Put as second parameter the expected value, so it will evaluate to true in case of nulls.

Comment: yes,i got the expected result.Thanks,i really appreciate your help.